# Does commiting a git repo containing a submodule affect the submodule repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repository containing a git submodule.  Everytime I try to commit I am told I cannot commit at this time and to sort all dependencies.  Could this be the fact that I have a submodule?

error message:

error: Entry 'sphere.py' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Where is your sphere.py file? I guess it's not in your submodule. Your submodule is not affected by any commit of the parent module.